# Testcafe Getting all Cookies from domain, store them in Object / Array and check if the Names of the Cookies are in an Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to Testcafé and need to get all Cookies from a Website, store them in an Object or Array and see, if the name of the Cookie matches against an Array of Strings to see if some Cookies are set; this needs to be done in Typescript; in pure Javascript would be easier, but these are the Requirements.

In order to achieve this, I implemented an Interface with all the Properties that I need from the Cookies:

```
class CookieInterface {
    static getName: string;

    constructor(domain: string, name: string, expirationDate: bigint,hostOnly: boolean, httpOnly: boolean,
                path: string, sameSite: string, secure: boolean, session: boolean, storeId: number,value: bigint,
                id: number) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
        this.hostOnly = hostOnly;
        this.httpOnly = httpOnly;
        this.path = path;
        this.sameSite = sameSite;
        this.secure = secure;
        this.session = session;
        this.name = name,
        this.storeId = storeId,
        this.value = value,
        this.id = id
    }

    domain: string
    expirationDate: bigint
    hostOnly: boolean
    httpOnly: boolean
    name: string
    path: string
    sameSite: string
    secure: boolean
    session: boolean
    storeId: number
    value: bigint
    id: number

    getName(cookieName: string){
     
    }
}

export {
    CookieInterface
};
```

This is the implementation  for the Testcase I came up with so far:

```
import 'testcafe';
import consentLayer from '../../page-objects/consent-layer';
import {ClientFunction, Selector} from 'testcafe';
import {CookieInterface} from './cookieInterface';

fixture('Cookie Checker')
    .page('http://www.mywebsite.com')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.1)
        await t.maximizeWindow()
    })

test
    .disablePageCaching
    .timeouts({
        pageLoadTimeout:    1000,
        pageRequestTimeout: 1000
    })
    ('should check if all relevant Cookies are set', async t => {

        let getCookies = ClientFunction(() => ()
```

TODO: Implement a Function that gets all the Cookies or uses the Interface and compare the property name against an Array of Strings
)

```
        let getCookieName = CookieInterface.getName;

        await t.wait(3000);
        await t.navigateTo('http://www.mywebsite.com')
        const cookies1 = await getCookies();
        await t.expect(cookies1.length).gt(
            0
        )

        await t.switchToIframe(Selector('*[id^=sp_message_iframe_]'));
        await t.expect(Selector('button[title="Accept all"]').exists).ok();
        await t.switchToMainWindow();
        await consentLayer.clickAcceptButton();
        await t.eval(() => location.reload(true))
        const cookies2 = await getCookies();
        await t.expect(cookies2.length).gt(
            0
        )
        await t.expect(Selector('*[id^=sp_message_iframe_]').exists).notOk();
        await t.expect(Selector('button[title="Accept All"]').exists).notOk();
    });
```

This is were I am stuck at the moment and would hence appreciate any hints or help, especially on how to get the Names from all the Cookies and compare them to an Array of Strings; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TestCafe 1.19.0 version there is no need to invent complicated workarounds to interact with the browser cookies. Our cookie management API offers a flexible and cross-browser way to set, get, or delete page cookies even those with the `HttpOnly` attribute. Read more in the [Release notes](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management).

The following example shows a common case of working with cookie.

```js
fixture`Cookies API`;
 
test('get/set cookie test', async t => {
   const name  = 'foo';
   const value = 'bar';
 
   var expires = new Date();
   expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 3); //cookies for 3 days
 
   await t.setCookies({
       name,
       value,
       expires
   });
 
   const cookies = await t.getCookies();
 
   await t.expect(cookies[0]).contains({ name, value, expires });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe does not offer a standard way to get cookies with their metadata. We are working on mechanisms for receiving cookies as a part of this [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5964).

The easiest way is as follows:

```js
const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => document.cookie);
```

However, it will only return `name=value` pairs.

Here are some workarounds:

###### Use `cookieStore`:

```js
const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => cookieStore.getAll());
```

In this case, TestCafe must be launched with the `--hostname localhost` flag, and Chrome with the `--allow-insecure-localhost` flag. So the run command might look like this: `testcafe "chrome: --allow-insecure-localhost" --hostname localhost test.js`
This method has two disadvantages:

1. Due to proxying, some object fields that you receive will be invalid.
2. In the future, the values returned by the cookieStore functions may change.

###### Read cookies directly from the file system:

In Windows Chrome stores a cookie in a file: `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`.
This method has the following disadvantages:

1. In each OS, each browser has its own path to files.
2. It will be difficult to understand the data storage formats.
3. You will have access to the file system only if the client is running on the same computer (it will be impossible to run tests remotely).

###### Intercept cookies:

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `About`
    .page`about:blank`;

test('cookie hook test', async t => {
    const setCookie = ClientFunction(string => document.cookie = string);
    const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => document.cookie);

    const name    = 'foo';
    const value   = 'bar';
    const expires = Date.now() - Date.now() % 1000 + 60000;

    await setCookie(`${name}=${value}; expires=${(new Date(expires)).toUTCString()}`);

    const cookie = await getCookie();

    await t.expect(cookie).eql({ [name]: { name, value, expires } });
})
    .before(async t => {
        const setCookieHooks = ClientFunction(() => {
            const cookie = {};

            document.__defineGetter__('cookie', () => cookie);
            document.__defineSetter__('cookie', raw => {
                const pairs  = raw.split(';').filter(string => !!string).map(string => string.trim().split('='));

                const [name, value] = pairs.shift();

                const result = { name, value };

                pairs.forEach(([key, val]) => result[key] = val);

                result.expires = result.expires ? Date.parse(result.expires) : null;

                cookie[name] = result;
            });
        });

        await setCookieHooks();
    });
```

Comment: You are amazing - I had a separate problem unrelated to the question - using self-signed cert for HTTPS TestCafe. I kept trying `testcafe chrome --allow-insecure-localhost [...]` but it didn't work. Turns out you had to wrap `chrome --allow-insecure-localhost` in quotes! Wish this was stated in TestCafe's docs...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will suggest to the team to include this in the documentation.